How can i convert automatic created code into a class instead of a string?
I'm trying to have a script create a file automatically by passing two parameters

newName
List of strings with elements to be added to the end of newName

This is what my result should look like:
def get_state_order() -> list[SquadState]:
    """Returns the order of the states of the exercise"""
    return [SquadState.DOWN, SquadState.UP]

However, unfortunately it looks like this, i.e. it consists of strings in the array. Unfortunately, I failed for a bit too long trying to convert each element of the list into a class object with the name exercise_name(elem).
def get_state_order() -> list[SquadState]:
    """Returns the order of the states of the exercise"""
    return ['SquadState.DOWN', 'SquadState.UP']

Here is my code
file = f"""
....
....
...
def get_state_order() -> list[{exercise_name.capitalize()}State]:
    \"\"\"Returns the order of the states of the exercise\"\"\"
    return {list(newName + abc for abc in states)}
...
....
...
"""

I tried to change the type of each elem from the list comprehension.
newName = exercise_name+"State."

this is the error i get everytime when i am trying to fix it with some type changing functions:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/PycharmProjects/KI/et_ki/models/exercises/automatisierung.py", line 91, in <module>
    create_exercise_file(exercise_name, states)
  File "/Users/work/PycharmProjects/KI/et_ki/models/exercises/automatisierung.py", line 67, in create_exercise_file
    return {list(exercise_name(newName + abc) for abc in states)}
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/work/PycharmProjects/KI/et_ki/models/exercises/automatisierung.py", line 67, in <genexpr>
    return {list(exercise_name(newName + abc) for abc in states)}
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable


FWIW, code generation is rarely the right answer to any problem.

You have a list of strings and when it is printed it includes proper quotes around the strings, there are several ways to get around this but the main issue is that when a list is printed it uses the representation of strings:
>>> print(str("hi")) # what we want it to do
hi
>>> print(repr("hi")) # what it is actually doing
'hi'
>>> print(["hi", "there"]) # repr gets called for each element in a list
['hi', 'there']

One easy way that seems like it'd be the most useful for your use case is to have a custom class that overrides the __repr__ method to pass the string directly:
class Symbol(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self # don't add quotes or escape special characters

Then you can wrap your strings that represent code symbols in this class to be represented raw:
>>> x = Symbol("SquadState.UP")
>>> print([x,x])
[SquadState.UP, SquadState.UP]


but as deceze already said, your problem is stemming from trying to wrap code in strings which is almost certainly not the best way to do things, it might make more sense to write a library that can be called from several codes instead of several calls to a generate code function

I have no idea why you need this but you can change the line:
return {list(newName + abc for abc in states)}

to
return [{", ".join([newName + abc for abc in states])}]

Note that I put brackets outside of the f-string and I created the body of that list by joining ,  to the result list comp.
Here is the full code:
exercise_name = "SquadState"
newName = exercise_name + "State."

states = ["UP", "DOWN"]

file = f"""
def get_state_order() -> list[{exercise_name.capitalize()}State]:
    \"\"\"Returns the order of the states of the exercise\"\"\"
    return [{", ".join([newName + abc for abc in states])}]
"""
print(file)

output:

def get_state_order() -> list[SquadstateState]:
    """Returns the order of the states of the exercise"""
    return [SquadStateState.UP, SquadStateState.DOWN]



Thank you very much, i really spend like 2 hours on this because i never did something like this. I need this automatic created code for an KI-Framework to train new data and to train new data it needs those files. I am simply trying to automize the process to train new data over an website to the KI
